# Android Studio not detecting changes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu

I am new to Android Java programming.
Trying to make a simple app.
All goes smootly until i want to add a menu...
This is how i tried:
[image]
[image]
After that I added the code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**No errors, but than any changes I do to menu_main.xml dont go to the app.**
After a lot of head-scraching i realised Android Studio doesnt read this file...
The only way to force it to read the file is to "Reformat Code" on the entire app...
Everytime i change this file i have to do it...
Restarting Android Studio (even my PC and phone tbh) didnt work.
Removing this file didnt help either (AS doesnt even notice the file is gone until I "Reformat Code").
Im guessing that because I manually add this file than it doesnt register as part of the app...?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if You have problem's like that try to **Rebuild Project**,

[image]

or remove folder '**projectname/app/build**'. Temporary file **build**.

If that won't help You can **Invalidate Caches/Restart**

[image]

Comment: "Rebuild Project" gives temporary solution... I'd have to click it everytime I change that xml file. The other solutions dont work at all... wish there was a way to force the rebuild on every app run

Comment: If You have older version of Android Studio, You can try to disable Instant Run. If it won't help try to disable 'Power Save Mode', Ctrl+Shit+A and type 'Power Save'.

Comment: latest versian of Android Studio, disabled instant run and same, power save was never on... i believe Android Studio keeps a list of all files relevant to the project and siply doesnt add the xml to that list